# android place picker closes after launch works on one pc but not the other

Tags: android, google-places

i am using the place picker provided by google, when i launch my app from android studio on one laptop the place picker works perfectly, but on my other laptop (syncing projects between laptops via source tree and Bitbucket) it automatically closes, I'm not sure why,I of course added the following lines to the manifest:

```
 <meta-data android:name="com.google.android.geo.API_KEY"
            android:value="ADD_YOUR_API_KEY_HERE" />
```

Answer (score 0):

you need to sign up for API key first
https://developers.google.com/places/android/signup